# Find length of the largest region in Boolean Matrix

Tags: java, foreach

I got this class who count the biggest island of "1" in the matrix, but he's island concept is *"Two cells are said to be connected if they are adjacent to each other horizontally, vertically, or diagonally."*

I need help to remove the diagonally step.

```java
class GFG {
    static int ROW, COL, count;

    static boolean isSafe(int[][] M, int row,
                          int col, boolean[][] visited) {
        return ((row >= 0) && (row < ROW) && (col >= 0)
                && (col < COL) && (M[row][col] == 1 &&
                !visited[row][col]));
    }

    static void DFS(int[][] M, int row,
                    int col, boolean[][] visited) {
        int[] rowNbr = {-1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1};
        int[] colNbr = {-1, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1};

        visited[row][col] = true;

        for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
            if (isSafe(M, row + rowNbr[k], col + colNbr[k], visited)) {
                count++;
                DFS(M, row + rowNbr[k], col + colNbr[k], visited);
            }
        }
    }

    static int largestRegion(int[][] M) {
        boolean[][] visited = new boolean[ROW][COL];
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
                if (M[i][j] == 1 && !visited[i][j]) {
                    DFS(M, i, j, visited);
                    result = Math.max(result, count);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int M[][] = {{0, 0, 1, 1},
                    {1, 0, 1, 1},
                    {0, 1, 0, 0},
                    {0, 0, 0, 0}};
        ROW = 4;
        COL = 4;
        System.out.println(largestRegion(M));
    }
}
```

The printed response is 6, but i need he returns 4 i tried everything by now, but i can't resolve. 
The original post of the algorithm: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-length-largest-region-boolean-matrix/

Comment: The `rowNbr` and `colNbr` arrays in the `DFS` method defines the 8 directions of adjacency, e.g. at index 0 they specify the (-1,-1) diagonal delta. **Reduce the arrays** to only specify the 4 directions you want.

Comment: its not about only 4 directions, is about connected side by side, example: 
{{0, 0, 1, 1},
 {1, 0, 1, 1},
 {0, 1, 0, 0},
 {0, 0, 0, 0}}
This should return 4;
{{1, 1, 1, 1},
 {1, 0, 1, 1},
 {0, 1, 0, 0},
 {0, 0, 0, 0}}
this, should return 7.

Comment: You question is about not wanting the 4 diagonal directions used by the code you copied (incorrectly), leaving only the 4 up/down/left/right directions, so in what way is it "not about only 4 directions"? Your comment makes no sense.

Comment: *"The printed response is 6"* --- No, the printed response is 5, because you **didn't copy the code correctly** from the [original post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-length-largest-region-boolean-matrix/). Your code is missing a `count = 1;` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to change the coordinates of neighbor array to size of 4.

```
int rowNbr[] = { -1, 0, 0, 1}; 
int colNbr[] = { 0, -1, 1,  0};
```

and iterate four times

```
 for (int k = 0; k < 4; ++k)
```

[The updated code:](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/w3qXO6zecN)

Comment: with your suggested alteration the return was 3, i need the example matrix return 4.

Comment: @Scarabelo If you **copy the code** from the [original post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-length-largest-region-boolean-matrix/) ***correctly***, it would work. Your code is missing a `count = 1;` statement.